# Copy element state without knowing which

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I got a page with different charts in a layout, but I want to display these charts in fullscreen when double clicking on it for example. Is there a way to copy an already rendered component including its state and so on, because the charts have sliders to change the interval etc... I think the most easy way would just to put a conditional to choose to render a graph fullscreen or just the page itself, but what could be an efficient way to know which chart was selected and to transfer these states, any thoughts?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. Don't tag your title.

Comment: Sound like you could benefit from using the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)